# Simple drag and drop with pure javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to be able to drag block which is clicked by mouse over the divs that exist with more than one with same class name and drop them to more than one div with same class name. I did this for only one object to drag and I can drop this to div where I want.
How can I create loop this for every div with same icon class name?
[my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQ3QO.jpg)

```js
var ball = document.querySelector(".icon");
let currentDroppable = null;

ball.onmousedown = function(event) { //event mouseun hareketi

    let shiftX = event.clientX - ball.getBoundingClientRect().left; //event.clientX mouseun başlangıçtaki yeri, bu mouseun yeni pozisyonunu calculate eder
    let shiftY = event.clientY - ball.getBoundingClientRect().top;

    ball.style.position = 'absolute';
    ball.style.zIndex = 1000;
    document.body.append(ball);

    moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

    function moveAt(pageX, pageY) { //elementi yeni pozisyonuna set eder
        ball.style.left = pageX - shiftX + 'px';
        ball.style.top = pageY - shiftY + 'px';
    }

    function onMouseMove(event) {
        moveAt(event.pageX, event.pageY);

        ball.hidden = true;
        let elemBelow = document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY);
        ball.hidden = false;

        if (!elemBelow) return;

        let droppableBelow = elemBelow.closest('.grid-item'); // en yakın grid item
        if (currentDroppable != droppableBelow) {
            if (currentDroppable) { // null when we were not over a droppable before this event
                leaveDroppable(currentDroppable);
            }
            currentDroppable = droppableBelow;
            if (currentDroppable) { // null if we're not coming over a droppable now
                // (maybe just left the droppable)
                enterDroppable(currentDroppable);
            }
        }
    }

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove); //mouseu taşımaya başladığında bu func çağırılır

    ball.onmouseup = function() { //mousea basmayı bıraktığın zaman olacaklar (stop moving)
        document.removeEventListener('mousemove', onMouseMove);
        ball.onmouseup = null;
        if (currentDroppable != null) { // yerleşecek yer bulduysa
            ball.style.top = currentDroppable.offsetTop + 7 + 'px';
            ball.style.left = currentDroppable.offsetLeft + 7 + 'px';
        } else { //yerleşecek yer bulamadıysa default bir yere götür
            ball.style.top = '10px';
            ball.style.left = '10px';
        }
    };

};

function enterDroppable(elem) {
    elem.style.background = 'pink';
}

function leaveDroppable(elem) {
    elem.style.background = '';
}

ball.ondragstart = function() {
    return false;
};
```

```css
html,
body {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 10;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-gap: 5px;
    grid-template-columns: 15vh 15vh 15vh 15vh 15vh 15vh 15vh 15vh;
    grid-template-rows: 15vh 15vh;
    padding: 80px;
    position: relative;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
}

.grid-item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    border: 1px dashed rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-align: center;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.icon {
    border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
    height: 15vh;
    width: 15vh;
    background-color: rgba(62, 104, 139, 0.582);
    cursor: pointer;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="grid.css" />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="icon"></div> <!--I want to add lots of div with icon class name here-->
    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item">1</div>
        <div class="grid-item">2</div>
        <div class="grid-item">3</div>
        <div class="grid-item">4</div>
        <div class="grid-item">5</div>
        <div class="grid-item">6</div>
        <div class="grid-item">7</div>
        <div class="grid-item">8</div>
        <div class="grid-item">9</div>
        <div class="grid-item">10</div>
        <div class="grid-item">11</div>
        <div class="grid-item">12</div>
        <div class="grid-item">13</div>
        <div class="grid-item">14</div>
        <div class="grid-item">15</div>
        <div class="grid-item">16</div>
    </div>

    <script src="grid.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you please add a Code Snippet on fiddle so we can run it and check them? along with CSS ?

Comment: Relevant: [I've been told to create a “runnable” example with “Stack Snippets”, how do I do that?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: I added code snippet